# How could I have Text at the bottom of this screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have a page/screen that's opened after a FAB is pressed. On this page/screen, I'd like to have text at the very bottom (trying to show the date here) but I'm not sure how I'd do this with the way I have laid out my widgets.

On the page, I have the Widget build as shown below:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Add Object')), body: body(context),
      ),
      onWillPop: () async {
        return true;
      }
    );
  }
```

Which references my Widget body:

```
  Widget body(BuildContext ctx) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: EditableText(
              controller: titleController,
              focusNode: titleFocus,
              cursorColor: Colors.blue,
              backgroundCursorColor: Colors.blue,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                )
              )
            ),
          ),
          Divider(),
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: EditableText(
                controller: contentController,
                maxLines: 600,
                focusNode: contentFocus,
                cursorColor: Colors.blue,
                backgroundCursorColor: Colors.red,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20
                )
              )
            )
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

With this layout, how would I go by putting text at the very bottom? I was thinking a Bottom Navigation Bar, but I don't think that's the correct use of it if I am just trying to have some text at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Align widget within Expanded

```
Expanded(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Text('Something'),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: For some reason, putting this under the last Flexible, it doesn't really put the text at the bottom of the screen? The text is half way

Answer (score 0):

Using Align widget with a Flexible with an high flex value will do the trick:

```
Flexible(
  flex: 15,
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Text('text')
  )
),
```

I don't like this solution but it's a good temporary one